# Windows: Add Pipe to Select FD_SET

Tags: c++, sockets, select, pipe, winsock

In windows, how does one add a pipe to a select() read set. 
After creating one:

```
HANDLE H_TimerPipeRead, H_TimerPipeWrite;
CreatePipe(&H_TimerPipeRead, &H_TimerPipeWrite, NULL, 0)
```

Trying to add the pipe to the set:

```
FD_SET(H_TimerPipeRead, &fds);
```

Yields the error:

```
operand types are incompatible ("SOCKET" and "HANDLE")
```

How do I get a socket from the pipe? Or how am I supposed to create a pipe in such a way that it can be added to the fds set.

Comment: On POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) pipes are file descriptors just like sockets. However in the Windows world they are not the same. A socket is not the same as a pipe-handle or as a file-handle. You have to figure out other ways to poll for events from both sockets and pipe handles, and that way will only work with Windows.

Comment: Bugger, really? I'll edit my question to make it clearer that it's for windows. But that's annoying, I'll have to redesign somehow.

Comment: Bugger indeed. :) I haven't used pipes in Windows myself, so unfortunately can't help you further.

Comment: Forget polling and use asynchronous I/O.

Comment: Yes, you *should* use asynchronous I/O *when possible*. But sometimes polling is just easier, or is the only solution (for instance, pipes from `CreatePipe()` do not support overlapped I/O).  You can use `PeekNamedPipe()` to poll a pipe (despite its name, it also works on anonymous pipes). Coupled with a timeout on `select()`, you would be able to monitor both pipes and sockets without having to resort to using asynchronous I/O or multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have instead ended up using a socket for the same purpose. There may be issues with this approach, but I don't know about them, and ignorance can be bliss.